# Easier way to follow links with Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I have the following code in a scrapy spider:

```
class ContactSpider(Spider):
    name = "contact"
    # allowed_domains = ["http://www.domain.com/"]
    start_urls = [

        "http://web.domain.com/DECORATION"
    ]
    BASE_URL = "http://web.domain.com"

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.selector.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"MAIN")]/a/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            absolute_url = self.BASE_URL + link
            yield Request(absolute_url,  headers= headers, callback=self.second)
```

I'm surprised there is not a simpler way in scrapy to follow links rather than build each absolute_url. Is there a a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For absolute urls you can use `urlparse.urljoin`, `Response` already has a shortcut for that via `response.urljoin(link)`. So your code could easily be replaced by:

```
def parse(self, response):
    links = response.selector.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"MAIN")]/a/@href').extract()
    for link in links:
        yield Request(response.urljoin(link),  headers=headers, callback=self.second)
```

You can also use scrapy `LinkExtractors` which extract links according to some rules and manages all of the joining automatically.

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
def parse(self, response):
    le = LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[contains(@class,"MAIN")]/a/@href')
    links = le.extract_links(response)
    for link in links:
        yield Request(link.url,  headers= headers, callback=self.second)
```

Regarding more automated crawling experience - scrapy has `CrawlSpider` which uses set of rules to extract and follow links on each page. You can read about it more here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider
The docs have some examples of it as well.

Comment: I would recommend mentioning `CrawlSpider` first: I believe it's the out-of-the-box spider class for this kind of use-case.